# How does plot.cld in multcomp package calculate boxes?

Tags: r, boxplot, mixed-models

To visualise significant differences with letters there is a plotting function in the multcomp package:

```
library(multcomp)
tuk <- glht(model, linfct = mcp(effect = "Tukey"))
plot(cld(tuk))
```

How are the boxes calculated (i.e. upper and lower quartiles and whiskers)? I could not find any information about that in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically just a regular `boxplot`. For instance with the `warpbreaks` data:

```
# load data
data(warpbreaks)
# model 
amod <- aov(breaks ~ tension, data = warpbreaks)
tuk <- glht(amod, linfct = mcp(tension = "Tukey"))
# plot
plot(cld(tuk))
```

This is pretty much the same as

```
boxplot(breaks ~ tension, data = warpbreaks)
# OR
boxplot(split(warpbreaks$breaks, warpbreaks$tension))
```

`boxplot` uses `boxplot.stats`, which uses `stats.fivenum` to calculate the necessary statistics. Notice that this differs slightly from the `quantile` function with `probs=c(0,.25, .5, .75, 1)` and `na.rm=TRUE`. In its simplest form (no `NA`'s, length>0), `fivenum` looks like this:

```
fivenum <- function (x) 
{
  x <- sort(x)
  n <- length(x)
  n4 <- floor((n + 3)/2)/2
  d <- c(1, n4, (n + 1)/2, n + 1 - n4, n)
  0.5 * (x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)])
}
```

Comment: Ah sure, thanks! I was majorly confused because it looked different from my ggplot2 version and couldn't figure out why but now I remember that hinges are calculated differently so it all makes sense ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code:

`plot.cld()` calls `boxplot()`, therefore the information you're looking for can be found in `?boxplot.stats`.

Comment: Thanks, what I don't get though is how to manually calculate the hinges from my `lmer` output, it's clear that the median in the boxplot is the estimate but how do I calculate quartiles for that?